Flutter Cannot hit a render box with no size
When the screen is in mobile view I want the tab bar to be below the expansiontile section, but I'm not sure how to achieve that as I have been getting cannot hit a render box with no size. This entire column is placed into another column, when i comment out the tab bar and tab bar view there is no error, so the problem is with the tab bar. The pink container in the image i attached is where i want to position the tab bar and tabbar view.
Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            TabBar(
                              controller: _tabController,
                              tabs: [
                                Tab(text: 'Videos'),
                                Tab(text: 'Infographic'),
                                Tab(text: 'Articles'),
                              ],
                              labelColor: Colors.black,
                              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                              indicatorColor: Colors.red,
                            ),
                             SizedBox(height: 10),
                            Container(
                              height: 400,
                              child: TabBarView(
                                controller: _tabController,
                                children: [
                                  // Videos Tab Content
                                  Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Videos Tab Content for ${_currentIndex + 1}',
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  // Infographic Tab Content
                                  Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Infographic Tab Content for ${_currentIndex + 1}',
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  // Articles Tab Content
                                  Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Articles Tab Content for ${_currentIndex + 1}',
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),```


This can often happen with TabBar and TabBarView when they are used without being properly wrapped in a widget that gives them defined constraints.
In a Column widget, children are laid out vertically, but the column doesn't impose any specific constraints on its children's width or height, aside from trying to let them be as big as they want in the vertical axis. However, TabBarView expects to know its available size to correctly layout its children. When it doesn't have this information—like when it's placed directly in a Column without any constraints—it doesn't know how to size itself and thus can't be rendered properly.
Given your description and the structure you provided, one solution is to ensure that your TabBar and TabBarView are enclosed within a structure that provides them with defined height (and possibly width) constraints. One common approach is to use a Flexible widget or an Expanded widget for the TabBarView, which tells it to fill the available space in the column. Since you mentioned the entire setup is within another column, using Expanded or similar is crucial to ensure the TabBarView knows how much space it has to fill.
Here is an adjusted version of your code snippet incorporating Expanded:
 Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    // Your ExpansionTile section here
    // For demonstration, just a placeholder Container
    Container(
      color: Colors.teal, // Placeholder color
      height: 200, // Placeholder height
      child: Center(
        child: Text('ExpansionTile Section Here'),
      ),
    ),
    // TabBar section
    TabBar(
      controller: _tabController,
      tabs: [
        Tab(text: 'Videos'),
        Tab(text: 'Infographic'),
        Tab(text: 'Articles'),
      ],
      labelColor: Colors.black,
      unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
      indicatorColor: Colors.red,
    ),
    SizedBox(height: 10),
    // Use Expanded for TabBarView to fill the available vertical space
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        // Pink container as per your description
        color: Colors.pink,
        child: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: [
            // Videos Tab Content
            Center(child: Text('Videos Tab Content')),
            // Infographic Tab Content
            Center(child: Text('Infographic Tab Content')),
            // Articles Tab Content
            Center(child: Text('Articles Tab Content')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)

In this setup, the Expanded widget around the TabBarView tells it to expand and fill the available space in its parent column. This should resolve the sizing issue, as Expanded will provide the TabBarView with the necessary constraints.
Remember, for this to work as expected, your _tabController needs to be initialized with the correct length and disposed of when the widget's state is disposed. Make sure your widget is a StatefulWidget and includes these implementations if it hasn't already.
